# How to compare second patch set with origin in gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

Is there a way to check the diff of 2nd or 3rd patch set with origin? Not with previous patch set or base

Scenario is; Initially I review first patch set and gave review comments and subsequently reviewed second patch set with review comments incorporated. Now before merging to origin I want to check the second patch set with origin.

Something like this [Review board - Compare 5th review set with origin](https://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/dev/users/reviews/reviewing-diffs/#viewing-other-diff-revisions)
Is it possible at all with gerrit?

**Update:**

Comparing base with patch set 1 shows diff with origin and patch 1
[image: Diff with base and patch 1]
`log.warn` messages were not present in base but where added and review comment was given.

Comparing base with patch set 2 shows the diff between patch 1 and patch 2. Not with origin and patch 2
[image]
Now base shows as log message is already there which are not present in origin.

The commits were amended. if that matters.

Comment: Please clarify what is the difference between "origin" and "base".

Comment: My understanding is base is origin.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Click any of the changed files to see the diff, either side-by-side diff or unified diff. On the top, you can see "Patch Set Base 1 2 3" on both sides. The left part is on Base by default and the right is on the current patch set by default. You can switch to another patch set on both sides. The unified diff is almost the same.

Comment: In my case I have base, 1, 2 And base is first patch set, 1 is first patch set with my comments(my review comments), 2 is new review. In left I can not select origin

Comment: Forgot to mention the git commit was amended btw. If it matters

Comment: @DheerajJoshi base is the origin

Answer (score 0):

You're already doing the diff process correctly, but really the log.warn line is not expected to show in the base-patchset2 diff.

I can think in some possibilities for this issue:

1. Have you rebased de change?
2. You have a special situation in the code and the change that is fooling us. It's not possible to analyse because the other source code lines are missing in your images. Is it possible to show the missing lines?
3. There's a bug. What Gerrit version are you using?